# accessing index of items in list using robot framework on react components

Tags: robotframework

I have some experience with the robot framework but none with react however I have a react component that I need to test.

I would like to access the index of items in a list but cannot seem to see all of the items.

```
<div class="Select-value">
  <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-10-- 
  value- 
  item">Item1</span>
</div>

<div class="Select-input">
  <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-10--value" aria- 
  expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" class="Select-input" role="combobox" 
  value="">
</div>
```

How can obtain the index of each item from the input list? Usually in non react I see a very straight forward list with the chosen item identified.

Looking inside the element I can see the index of each item by hovering over it:

```
<input aria-activedescendant="react-select-22--option-5" aria- 
expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="react-select-22--list" 
class="Select-input" role="combobox" value="">
```

I plan to create a for loop that starts on the 1st item and cycles through them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Get Web Elements` with selector `//input[@class='Select-input']` and then iterate on them.

Here is an example:

```
@{my_list}=    Get Web Elements    xpath=//input[@class='Select-input']
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{my_list}
    Log to Console    ${element}
END
```

Comment: having tried this, only one element is returned, I assume the currently chosen item. What I really need is all of the items yet I cannot see them in the dom anywhere.

If I open the element I can see the index of the item by hovering over each of them represented by the aria-activedescendant="react-select-22--option-5"

Comment: I believe so, I am unable to find any real guidance for locating react components through the robot framework online anywhere

Comment: I only ever seem to be able to return the currently chosen item, rather than all of them

Answer (score 0):

the react component has has a hidden element that was only accessible once the dropdown menu was open:

`[@class="Select-menu-outer"]` was revealed after submitting a click to the dropdown menu itself.

Comment: were you able to access all the elements from the dropdown?